# Erro ao imprimir o valor da propriedade owner.screenname e owner.url (Dailymotion Data API)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, rest

Ao executar o GET para os recursos PLAYLIST e VIDEO, tive um problema. Ao executar GET no meu console, a solicitação retorna corretamente os valores dos atributos owner.screenname e owner.url; no entanto, ao fazer a mesma solicitação por AJAX (jQuery), esses valores são apresentados como undefined (console do Google Chrome) . Vocês poderiam me dizer onde estou errando? Estou usando a Dailymotion Data API. Estou fazendo a chamada a partir de http://localhost: 8084 (Apache Tomcat)

Código:

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "GET",    
    url: "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezj5?fields=id,title,owner,owner.screenname,owner.url",    
    dataType: "json"  
})  
.done(function(data){    
    console.log(data.id);    
    console.log(data.title);    
    console.log(data.owner);     
    console.log(data.owner.screenname);     
    console.log(data.owner.url);     
})    
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){    
    console.log(jqXHR.status + textStatus + errorThrown);    
})    
.always(function(data) {    
    console.log(data);    
});
```

Console do Chrome:

```
x26ezj5  
Greetings  
x1fz4ii  
undefined  
undefined  
{id: "x26ezj5", title: "Greetings", owner: "x1fz4ii", owner.screenname: "Dailymotion API", owner.url: "https://www.dailymotion.com/DailymotionAPI"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o mesmo código, porém em `javascript puro`, obtive resultado.

Copie e cole este código no console no navegador e verás o resultado.

Acontece que você está dando `console.log()` em todos as propriedades do objeto `data` e onde retorna `undefined` é porque a propriedade não existe no objeto `data`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var uri = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezj5?fields=id,title,owner,owner.screenname,owner.url";

xhr.open("GET", uri, true);

//callback
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {         
         const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
         console.log(response)
    } else {
         console.log("offline");
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Wagner, obrigado pela contribuição! Consegui solucionar trocando: data.owner.screenname por data["owner.screenname"] e data.owner.url por data["owner.url"].